# mySQL UPDATE WHERE with subquery gives error

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to update a table with a subquery and always get an error.
Now i made a very simplified version (which makes not much sense but shows my error)

```
UPDATE a_test SET categoryID = '2956' WHERE id IN (
    (
        SELECT id from a_test
    )
)
```

This ends in this error:

```
#1093 - Table 's_articles_categories' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

Why do i get this error?
When i use aliasses for the table a_test i get the same error.

This is the full query i want to use with the same error:

```
UPDATE s_articles_categories SET categoryID = '2956' WHERE id IN
(
SELECT s_articles_categories.id FROM `s_articles`
LEFT JOIN s_articles_categories ON s_articles.id = s_articles_categories.articleID
WHERE s_articles_categories.categoryID NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM s_categories 
WHERE s_categories.id NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM s_categories WHERE parent IS NOT null GROUP BY parent)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to the simplified query is to wrap the subquery inside another subquery:

```
UPDATE a_test
SET categoryID = '2956'
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM a_test) x );
```

This trick forces MySQL to materialize the subquery on `a_test`, so that the values coming from the subquery aliased as `x` are not affected as the update proceeds.

Comment: I won't attempt an answer on the actual query because I can't see the data, and therefore don't really understand the logic.

Comment: Perfect, that is working also with the query i wanted to use. I learned something!